# Margins and Padding not displaying

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I'm creating a landing page using a responsive grid, on a clean template in Wordpress. I can't get my margins or padding to display on the desktop version, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong. They display fine on mobile, but no styling a try and apply to the_content will work.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

 /*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 2.5%;}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%;}

.span_11_of_12 {
width: 91.45%;}

.span_10_of_12 {
width: 82.91%;}

.span_9_of_12 {
width: 74.37%;}

.span_8_of_12 {
width: 65.83%;}

.span_7_of_12 {
width: 57.29%;}

.span_6_of_12 {
width: 48.75%;}

.span_5_of_12 {
width: 40.20%;}

.span_4_of_12 {
width: 31.66%;}

.span_3_of_12 {
width: 23.12%;}

.span_2_of_12 {
width: 14.58%;}

.span_1_of_12 {
width: 6.041%;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }

.span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12, .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
width: 100%; 
}}

#content-desktop {
display: inline; }

#content-mobile {
display: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#content-desktop {
display: none;}

#content-mobile {
display: inline;}

.content {
   padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%; }


#rightform {
   padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
color: white;
</style>
</head>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="section group">

    <div class="content">
    <div class="col span_6_of_12">

    <div id="content-desktop">
        Body Content Here
    </div>

    <div id="content-mobile">
        Mobile Body Content Here
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="rightform"> 
<div class="col span_6_of_12">
    <a name="taketest"></a>
```

Here is a form that's also not getting any padding on desktop.

```
</div>

<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_6_of_12" id="content-mobile">
         <div class="content">
         Mobile Body Copy Two
    </div>
   </div>

  <div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_3_of_12 ctabox" id="content-mobile">
        <a href="#taketest">
        <img src="http://polaron.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/CTA-Small.png" style="margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%; max-height:120px; vertical-align:middle" /> </a>

   </div> </div>
```

At less than 600px, everything works fine. Padding around all the text. But on Desktop? Nothing. It says it's there, but my text from the_content is right up against the edge of the window. If I try set a max-width or margins, that won't work either. What (probably very obvious thing!) am I missing?

Here is a link to the HTML and CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/dvrfc0dk/

Comment: If you are showing code with PHP in it, you require us to have PHP to help you which will eliminate people like me who don't use PHP. You should always display the rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting here! I've removed all references to PHP in my original code, and a link to the rendered HTML and CSS is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dvrfc0dk/

Comment: A link to a third party source for your example code is not allowed. You must supply all your markup and code that shows the problem here. Third party links change, disappear or go dead and help no one in the future with the same problem: [mcve] So does the markup and code you posted here show the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your padding will only shows up until 600px width since it's inside the 
    `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {`. Either add `max-width` for other format or place your `.content {
   padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%; }`. outside the `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {`